# One LVM volume across multiple mdadm arrays

Tags: lvm, software-raid

I'm about to set up a new nas and basically want to know if it's a bad or a good idea to have one lvm volume on multiple mirrored mdadm arrays, kind of like raid 10. I thought this would make it easier to expand the volume by just adding a new raid1 array to the volume. Is this smart or should I just go with plain mdadm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The up side to using lvm this way is that it does make expanding easy and the new drives don't have to be the same size.  On the other hand, a 4 disk mdadm raid10 configured to use the offset striping mode can give seqential read performance near that of a 4 disk raid0, but an lvm stripe on top of two mdadm raid1s only has the performance of two disks.